# How to disable CBC ciphers in Firefox

Tags: firefox, security, tls, cipher

The ssllabs.com browser check shows a list of cipher suites supported by my browser. Some are labeled as WEAK, I think because they do not support perfect forward secrecy.

I can disable some of them by going to `about:config`, typing in `ssl3`, and then changing the ones I don't want to false. (Yes, they still label it `ssl3`, but they still apply.) But, the ones shown at ssllabs as having CBC in the name do not appear on the list in Firefox, so I can't figure out how to disable those.

Anyone know how?

Comment: This is why Firefox allow you to add additional configuration in the @config be very careful you might not be able to access web pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do appear on the list in Firefox; they're just not *labelled* `cbc`. At the time they were added to Mozilla, CBC was the only cipher mode supported by SSL anyway, so it wasn't explicitly specified in the name (whereas GCM is a much later addition). You'll find them under `aes_128_sha` or `aes_256_sha` in about:config.

Perfect forward secrecy does not depend on the block cipher mode; it's determined by whether the cipher suite uses ephemeral DH – i.e. `ECDHE` and `DHE` ciphersuites provide PFS; other ones do not. SSL Labs will mark ciphersuites as weak if they use CBC **or** if they don't provide PFS.

This only applies up to TLSv1.2. Starting with TLSv1.3, none of the ciphersuites use CBC and all of them are PFS-capable (and the ciphersuite name no longer explicitly mentions "ECDHE" because it's mandatory in TLSv1.3). In the SSL Labs website, 0x13xx are TLSv1.3 ciphersuites, the others are for TLS≤v1.2.